# Error: the following arguments are required: new (How to Build an E-commerce Website with Django and Python)

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, web-development-server

I am trying to start this tutorial... I had to pip install a few packages and adjust requirements.txt a bit. Now, I'm trying to rename the project and I am getting an error:

> manage.py rename: error: the following arguments are required: new

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZvRrldjf1Y&t=1485s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

```
import os
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Renames a Django project'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('current', type=str, nargs='+',
                            help='The current Django project folder name')
        parser.add_argument('new', type=str, nargs='+',
                            help='The new Django project name')

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_project_name = kwargs['current'][0]
        new_project_name = kwargs['new'][0]

        # logic for renaming the files

        files_to_rename = [f'{current_project_name}/settings/base.py',
                           f'{current_project_name}/wsgi.py', 'manage.py']

        for f in files_to_rename:
            with open(f, 'r') as file:
                filedata = file.read()

            filedata = filedata.replace(current_project_name, new_project_name)

            with open(f, 'w') as file:
                file.write(filedata)

        os.rename(current_project_name, new_project_name)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(
            'Project has been renamed to %s' % new_project_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error.
In the video-tutorial a little different code

change

```
files_to_rename = [f'{current_project_name}/settings/base.py',
                           f'{current_project_name}/wsgi.py', 'manage.py']
```

to

```
files_to_rename = [f'demo'/settings.py', f'demo'/wsgi.py', 'manage.py']
```

add

```
folder_to_rename = 'demo'
```

change

```
filedata = filedata.replace(current_project_name, new_project_name)
```

to

```
 filedata = filedata.replace('demo', new_project_name)
```

and call

```
python manage.py rename demo programname
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be using a more recent version of Django than the video. In this case you'd want to type (to use the values in the video):

```
python manage.py rename demo djecommerce
```

The rename command now requires both the old foldername  and the new name for it.

Comment: I got [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'demo/settings/base.py'. I've tried to put the old folder name as djecommerce because that's the name of the project.

Comment: Solved! Thank you! I put "python manage.py rename djecommerce AzurEcom" and it worked. The default name was just djecommerce... Wow! Nice!